# "undefined reference to" linker error while working with templates

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, linker

I have a class Array

```
template <typename T>
class Array : public SequentialContainer<T>{
public:
    Array(Int size){local_vector.reserve(size);}
    Array(std::initializer_list<T> initializer_list){
        local_vector.assign(initializer_list);
    }
    virtual Boolean contains(T &object) const;
    virtual Boolean contains(Container<T> &container) const;
    virtual Int size() const;
    virtual T &operator[](Int idx);
    virtual T &get(Int idx);
    virtual void set(Int idx, const T &object);
    virtual Int indexOf(T &object);
    virtual Iterator<T> iterator() const;
};
```

All the methods are implemented like this in the Array.cpp file:

```
template <typename T>
Boolean Array<T>::contains(T &object) const {
//code
}
```

If i try to use this Array class in a main.cpp file:

```
Array<int> c = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
std::cout << c.[4] <<std::endl;
```

I am getting these linker errors:

```
undefined reference to `Array<int>::iterator() const'
undefined reference to `Array<int>::contains(int&) const'
undefined reference to `Array<int>::contains(Container<int>&) const'
etc...
```

for every single method of the Array class. All the files are in my cmake file and should be compiled.
Why I am getting this linker error? could someone explain me this please?

Comment: `Array.cpp` you have to put all template definitions in the header. Templates don't work like normal classes...

Comment: _"All the methods are implemented like this in the Array.cpp file:"_ Whoops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement template method or class in a cpp-file. Try to do this in a header

Comment: Actually you can. But they can then only be used in a limited way and with a small quantity of additional work.